# Calc 3 - Finding the Volume of Integral

Tags: calculus

Use spherical coordinates in order to compute the triple integral,

$$\iiint_D z^dV$$

where D is the region $D:= \{(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9, z \geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$.

I need help finding the bounds for $\phi$

I have the other two bounds. $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi, 0\leq \rho \leq3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x =\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi\\
y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi\\
z = \rho \cos \phi$

$ z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
\rho \cos\phi = \sqrt{\rho^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi}\\
\rho \cos\phi = \rho \sin \phi\\
1 = \tan \phi\\
\phi = \pi/4$

I am going to leave it to you to think about why it is $0\to\pi/4$ and not $\pi/4\to\pi/2$ or similar.

Comment: Ohh thanks. Yeah it starts at the top of the z axis and comes down?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to describe the region $D$ in spherical coordinates. Geometrically you looking at the region above a cone and below a sphere.

[image]

First calculate the intersection by converting equations $x^2+y^2 + z^2 = 9$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$;

$$\rho = 3  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \rho \cos \phi = \rho \sin \phi \Rightarrow \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

It now becomes clear that $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: pcos/phi = psin/phi = pi/4. you lost me there.

Comment: when does $cos \phi = \sin \phi$